# Installing Office into Windows Container (servercore:ltsc2019) failed with error code 17002

Tags: .net, azure, docker, containers, odt

## Error Message

ODT (Office Deployment Tool) log reported error when installing into Windows Container (Server Core): C2R client returned failing error code, error code: 17002

## Environments

- Behavior in Windows Server 2019 (1809) with Desktop Experience installed.

  - ODT installation Result: Succeeded.
  - test-o365.ps1: Succeeded.
- Behavior in Container (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019)

  - ODT installation Result: Negative (C2R client returned failing error code, error code: 17002)
  - test-o365.ps1: Negative: HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

## Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
WORKDIR C:/setup
COPY . . 
ENTRYPOINT startup.cmd
```

## startup.cmd

```
curl.exe https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/A/27AF1BE6-DD20-4CB4-B154-EBAB8A7D4A7E/officedeploymenttool_12325-20288.exe  --output .\
officedeploymenttool_12325-20288.exe
officedeploymenttool_12325-20288.exe /quiet /passive /extract:.
setup.exe /configure o365.xml
powershell -file test-o365.ps1
pause
```

## o365.xml

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="Monthly">
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <!--  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" Channel="Monthly" /> -->
  <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
  <Logging Level="Standard" Path="." />
  <!--  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />  -->
</Configuration>
```

## test-o365.ps1

```bsh
# Write current datetime into result.xlsx to verify that Office COM component is working.
$filename = [System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory + "\result.xlsx"
$filename
if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($filename )) {    
    Remove-Item $filename 
}
$xl=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible=$false
$wb=$xl.WorkBooks.Add()
$ws=$wb.WorkSheets.item(1)
$ws.Cells.Item(1,1)= [System.DateTime]::Now
$wb.SaveAs($filename)
$xl.Quit()
```

## More information

We are already aware of 'server-side Automation of Office' issues as mentioned in article [3]. At current stage, we are evaluating the possibility on running legacy ASP.NET application in Windows container, with Office/COM inter-operation enabled.

## References

1. [Overview of the Office Deployment Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool)
2. [What is the Server Core installation option in Windows Server?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core)
3. [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)

Comment: Any update? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for a while, and finally got it to work. I found the solution to the 17002 error was to run the setup.exe /configure config.xml while running the docker image interactively, and then committing that container. This worked for me on the windows:1809 image.

**Full writeup**

I'm copying the downloaded office files into the docker image separately, as I was having issues with getting the download to work from inside the docker file [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147624/install-excel-in-windows-server-2019-via-dockerfile-returns-non-zero-error-code/65293710#65293710). So I have the folder `Office` at the same level as the docker file with the contents of `setup.exe /download config.xml`. Then the docker file below builds a base image. I ran `docker run -it {IMAGEID} powershell`, navigate to C:\\odtsetup and with the interactive console run `setup.exe /configure config.xml`, exit the container and run

```
docker stop {CONTAINERID}
docker commit {CONTAINERID}`
```

I now have a base windows server image with docker installed, and can use it in the dockerfile for my application. If I need to update the server image or excel version I'll need to do this manually again, but I'm just thankful it's working.

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809
WORKDIR C:\\odtsetup
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/A/27AF1BE6-DD20-4CB4-B154-EBAB8A7D4A7E/officedeploymenttool_13426-20308.exe odtsetup.exe
RUN odtsetup.exe /quiet /norestart /extract:C:\\odtsetup
ADD config.xml .
ADD Office Office\\
```

**config.xml**

```
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="PerpetualVL2019">
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
      <Language ID="MatchOS" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Access" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Lync" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneDrive" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Outlook" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="PowerPoint" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Publisher" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Teams" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Word" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Updates Enabled="FALSE" />
  <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1"/>
  <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="TRUE" />
  <Remove All="TRUE">
  </Remove>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Running it interactively also worked for me. But I only have this issue with the windows:1809 base image. 

With windows:1903 the install works fine during the docker build. 

For windows:2004, when I try to check if Word is working after a successful install with new-object -comobject word.application, I obtain "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070520 A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)."

Comment: Actually, I fear that I have to add something else: The installation in 1809 is not successful in the interactive mode, it simply does not throw a non-zero exit code. If you check the logs in the %temp% folder, you will see that it stops at 94% and exits with 17002. Everything in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16 folder is missing (and maybe more?) so e.g. an activation via KMS is not possible to do with the opps.vbs script, which is missing. I don't know what else is missing, Word, Excel and PowerPoint work to some extent.

Comment: @Nick, my container gets stuck at '/configure' step. its neither moving ahead nor exiting the interactive mode.

Comment: @mfbieber were you able to resolve the 80070520 error?

Comment: @Nick What is odtsetup.exe? is it the exe we get from the link? because when i use the exact same scripts you wrote, i am getting below error:                        `odtsetup.exe : The term 'odtsetup.exe' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`