# Install Excel in Windows Server 2019 via Dockerfile returns non-zero error code 2147972583

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ms-office, windows-server-2019

I am trying to build an image of Windows Server 2019 with Excel installed. Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

WORKDIR C:\deploy\

# Install Office deployment tool
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/A/27AF1BE6-DD20-4CB4-B154-EBAB8A7D4A7E/officedeploymenttool_12827-20268.exe C:/deploy/deploymenttool_autoextract.exe
RUN C:/deploy/deploymenttool_autoextract.exe /quiet /passive /extract:C:/deploy

COPY configuration.xml C:/deploy

# Download Office
RUN .\setup.exe /download configuration.xml
# Install Office
RUN .\setup.exe /configure configuration.xml
```

On step setup.exe /download configuration.xml, an non-zero error code 2147972583 is returned. I've tried to google for such error code but can't seem to find anything.

Below's my configuration.xml in case something is wrong with it:

```
<Configuration>

  <Add OfficeClientEdition="32" Channel="PerpetualVL2019">
    <Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <!-- <RemoveMSI All="True" /> -->
  <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />
  <Logging Name="Setup.log" Path="C:\deploy" />

</Configuration>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the setup.log file? Why do you need to install Excel on a windows server?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev the setup file is extremely large with whole bunch of random errors everywhere so it wasn't helpful. I need it installed on windows server due to automation requirement and excel macro execution functionality.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, My reason for installing Excel on container is I need lightweight solution to run a python app (pywin32) that fetches Image from Excel Charts and sends it to Azure Data warehouse. It happens only once in month, so Container Instance is much cheaper than using actual VM

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue - digging through the log files, I get ServerReachabilityErrors.

```
{"MachineId": "b456094a29c44f4c9b0c17fb496209c3", "SessionID": "", "GeoID": 244, "Ver": "0.0.0.0", "C2RClientVer": "16.0.13231.20350", "ErrorCode": 30183, "ErrorType": "HttpTransportError", "AppVErrorSource": "", "ErrorMessage": "HttpTransportError (Sending Http GET request. Error: ServerReachabilityError (0x80072ee7) , Error:0x80072ee7)", "ErrorDetails": "", "ContextData": "{\"message\":\"Failed to connect\"}"}
```

This looks like an issue with the firewall settings - especially since microsoft tries 20 fallback cdns before giving up. If you're getting this, check firewall logs, and make sure the machine running the docker build has permissions to access `http://officecdn.microsoft.com/**`